# Trigger GitHub Webhook from GitHub PR comment

Tags: github-actions, google-cloud-build

I'd like to run a cloud build trigger by commenting on a GitHub PR.

So if I comment `/deploy` then it will hit this endpoint:

[https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{projectId}/triggers/{triggerId}:run](https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/%7BprojectId%7D/triggers/%7BtriggerId%7D:run)

[Endpoint Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/run)

I've read some articles related to actions, but I haven't come across a decent example.

Comment: Have you checked this already: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/chatops-for-pull-requests?

Comment: Or this: https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch

Comment: Thanks, these examples helped me work through how to approach this. The issue I came up against is that the API requires an Oauth 2.0 scope (and thus retrieving access token) to be called which adds some complexity.

Comment: have you fond an answer to this. I have the same requirement